# Inserir várias linhas de uma única consulta usando o FOR

Tags: php, laravel, orientação-a-objetos, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando dar um insert de vários dados usando o FOR mas não está dando certo.
A impressão que dá é que ele não está pegando os dados do FOR?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A espectitativa é que aconteça isso:

```
ID|id_proposta|id_produto|quantidade|valor|total
1 |8          |1         |2         |250  |2000
2 |8          |2         |9         |300  |1000
3 |8          |3         |7         |150  |9000
4 |8          |4         |8         |200  |40000
5 |8          |5         |3         |290  |25000
```

Segue o código:

**Controller**

```
public function create()
    {


   $dadosForm = $this->request->all();

    $proposta = $this->proposta;



    $proposta->save([$dadosForm]); //salvo uma parte do for
    $proposta_id = $proposta->id; //pego o ID Salvo



     $count = $this->ensaios->max('id');
    $proposta_ensaios = $this->proposta_ensaios; //Essa parte fica em cinza parece que nao esta funcionando

    for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){

    $proposta_ensaios = new PropostaEnsaios();

    $proposta_ensaios->id_proposta = $proposta_id; //Aproveito o ID Salvo
    $proposta_ensaios->id_produto = $i;
    $proposta_ensaios->quantidade = $this->request->get('quantidade_'.$i);
    $proposta_ensaios->valor= $this->request->get('valor_'.$i);
    $proposta_ensaios->total = $this->request->get('total_'.$i);


    $proposta_ensaios->save([$dadosForm]);


    }
```

Comment: `quantidade` não pode vir em branco é o que diz erro. Logo tem um problema em: `$this->request->get('quantidade_'.$i);`

Comment: Sim se voce olhar um pouco mais em baixo não é só a quantidade esta vindo em branco valor e total tb no erro estao como "null"
Sem o for funciona mas salva apenas 1 registro e eu tenho quase 30

Comment: Precisa ver se vem os valores nos inputs pode ser dê `undefined index: ...` Comenta o `save()` e faça um `echo '<pre>'; print_r($proposta_ensaios);`

Comment: [quantidade] => 
            [valor] => 
            [total] => 
Está zerado mas quando faço o echo '<pre>'; print_r($dadosForm); traz corretamente

Comment: No lugar de `$this->request->get('quantidade_'.$i)` não deveria ser então `$dadosForm['chave']` ?

Comment: É isso mesmo @rray! Comenta sua resposta para mim positivar!

Comment: Acho melhor vc (se quiser) criar a resposta imagino que possa dar mais detalhes do sobre como resolveu problema.

Comment: O Duro quando eu comento só consigo fechar a pergunta após 2 dias mas tudo bem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido com a ajuda do [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray)

Dentro do FOR ao invés de usar:

```
$proposta_ensaios->quantidade = $this->request->get('quantidade_'.$i);
$proposta_ensaios->valor= $this->request->get('valor_'.$i);
$proposta_ensaios->total = $this->request->get('total_'.$i);
```

Troquei por:

```
    $proposta_ensaios->quantidade = $dadosForm['quantidade_'.$i];
    $proposta_ensaios->valor= $dadosForm['valor_'.$i];
    $proposta_ensaios->total = $dadosForm['total_'.$i];
```